# how do i get last message from ctx.author in DM channel

Tags: python, discord.py

im making user market command thing
im trying to make cooltime so that i can prevant spam

so how do i get last message from ctx.author in DM channel
im using cogs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the channel via

```py
channel = ctx.author.dm_channel
```

Like documented [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.dm_channel).
This will return an `discord.DMChannel` object of which you can get the history

```py
lastMessage = await channel.history(limit=1).flatten()[0]
```

---

In total the call could look something like this

```py
channel = ctx.author.dm_channel 
if channel != None:
    messages = await channel.history(limit=1).flatten()
    if len(messages) != 0:
        lastMessage = messages[0]
        # lastMessage will be the last message in the channel
```